# Is it possible to return an 'accurate' object from a polymorphic container of pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism

I found out that whenever we want polymorphism, we need pointers or references, because storing a `Derived` instance in a `Base` variable 'slices' off anything that isn't defined in 'Base'.

(I suppose that's because `Derived` and `Base` instances don't necessarily occupy the same space in memory. Is that correct?)

So when we want a container that holds all kinds of objects, all derived from subclasses of `Base`, we need a container of pointers and not a container of actual objects.

And if we want a function that gets an object from this container and returns it 'as it is' (not sliced), we can do this:

```
Base* get_pointer(int index) {
   return container[index];
}
```

But say I want to do the following:

```
Base get_object(int index) {
   return *container[index];
}
```

I.e.: return a real object, not a pointer. Is this possible? Or should I simply always manage with pointers when I want any kind of polymorphism?

Comment: Do you want to return a **copy**? Possible but you (may) have trouble because you're returning base class. What you may/should do is to return a reference instead of a pointer.

Comment: `Base& get_object(int index) {` would return a reference, that is usable the same way as a _real object_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ With no slicing?

Comment: @user3150201 As long you don't copy the reference, there's no slicing: `Base& obj = y.get_obj(3);` let's you use `obj` the same way as you would use the original object instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that whenever we want polymorphism, we need pointers or references [...]  Is that correct?

That is absolutely correct. However, you are not limited to "plain" pointers built into the language. Smart pointers, such as `std::unique_ptr<T>` and `std::shared_ptr<T>` present a better alternative that lets you preserve polymorphic behavior.

> [I want to] return a real object, not a pointer. Is this possible?

You can do that, but the slicing would be back. The `Base` will be returned by value, so the result would be stripped of the derived functionality. This always happens when you pass or return by value (passing and returning are two sides of the same thing, so the basic mechanism in play is the same in both cases).

If you return `Base&` by reference, however, you would get the same syntax in the caller, and your objects would not get sliced:

```
Base& get_object(int index) {
   return *container[index];
}
```

The only catch is that the item in the container must remain in place while your code is holding a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

As you already mention, in many Object Oriented Progtramming Languages, where polymorphysm is required, pointers to [dynamic allocated] objects, are used to access derived members, instead of, plain [statically allocated] objects.

But, in C++, as others, have mention, you also have the option to use references instead, while other programming languages, doesn't have it, and, have to stick to pointers.

You mention a "data collection or data container" in your example. Many software that requires a large qty. of objects, such as data structures, rather use pointers to objects, in order to maximize memory usage.

Personally, I prefere to use pointers instead of references, not just for accessing the derived members, but, also for the previous explained reason.