# How to have a map with different types of values?

Tags: c++

I need a map that has int as a key and value which can be various types of objects

```
std::map<int, differenttypes*> mapping;
```

and extract that objects like:

```
 dialog* newDialog = mapping[let]; //let is some int
```

insert that value like:

```
 mapping[let] = newDialog2;
```

How would i do this with a map? For example differenttypes to take string, int etc.
Maybe using boost::variant?

Comment: All map values have to be of the same type. You probably can use runtime polymorphism, but the question is asked in too generic way to give any meaningful answer.

Comment: Exactly as you write it? Or do you want store pointers of various types in the same map?

Comment: i want differenttypes* to be for example string, int etc...

Comment: @MateuszW How will you know what the type is when you retrieve it?  See the hole in your design?

Comment: You can use a union and a "type tag" (enum or string) indicating what the union actually holds.

Comment: So you want all generic types? Or user defined classes?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider can you ellaborate on that? possibly giving some example?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider That can be used, but it will inevitably lead to the "big-if" or "big-switch" type of programming.

Comment: @Chiel probably like 5 user defined classes

Comment: @MateuszW  See my "big-if / big-switch" comment.  Do you want that?  If it's a string do this, if it's an int do that, if it's a double do something else, etc..Litter your application with code like that, and it becomes a maintenance headache.

Comment: The problem that I am trying to solve is to have a storage for pointers of 5 different objects with different types based on int.
For example if int is 1 return string object, if int is 2 return car object etc

Comment: Also, see this: [Storing objects of differing types in a container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738405/how-can-i-store-objects-of-differing-types-in-a-c-container)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i was looking at this boost::any and boost::variant but how would I cast/know type of the object returning

Comment: @MateuszW that's kind of the point people have been making. It's not a very good design to have an object that can be any type. You need some sort of runtime checking. I'm not familiar with boost::any and boost::variant to know what they offer. A better solution is to fix your design.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to return an 'accurate' object from a polymorphic container of pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26342950/is-it-possible-to-return-an-accurate-object-from-a-polymorphic-container-of-po)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `any` type that boost provides in the map-container (or any other container that you like)
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/any.html

> The boost::any class supports copying of any value type and safe checked extraction of that value strictly against its type.

To get implementation-specific information about an element's type use the following function member of `boost::any`

```
 const std::type_info & type() const;
```

Example here (using a std::list):
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/any/s02.html

Should be the safest and quickest approach.

Comment: how would I cast/know which object type it is when retrieving that from an enum?

Comment: @MateuszW boost::any has a member function type() which returns a std::type_info

Answer (score 1):

You can use a union and a "type tag" (enum or string) indicating what the union actually holds. Let's suppose you want to hold strings, ints and floats:

```
union valU { float f; int i; char *s; };
enum valE { fl, in, st };
struct variousT { valU val; valE type; };

void print(variousT v)
{
   switch(v.type)
   {
      case fl: printf("%f", v.val.f); break;
      case in:  printf("%d", v.val.i); break;      
      case st:  printf("%s", v.val.s); break;
   }
}
```

Of course `print` could be a member function, there should be overloaded setters in `variousT` which set the tag together with the value etc. But this is the raw mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own '`any`' type (using a nested `union` in a `struct`) and store that as a value in your map. However, non-primitive type like `std::string` are a little tricky here.

Here is some rudimentary example:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <map>

struct any {
    enum any_type:char { string_t = 0, int_t = 1 };
    any(){
    }
    any(const any& a) {
        this->type = a.type;
        switch (this->type) {
            case any_type::string_t: new(&(this->str)) std::string(a.str); break;
            case any_type::int_t   : this->i = a.i; break;
            /* more types */
        }
    }
    ~any(){
        switch (this->type) {
            case any_type::string_t: { if (str.size()) { str.std::string::~string(); } } break;  
            /* more types */
            default: ;
        }
    }
    std::string descr() const {
        switch (this->type) {
            case any_type::string_t: { std::stringstream s; s << "string : " << str; return s.str(); }  
            case any_type::int_t   : { std::stringstream s; s << "int    : " << i; return s.str(); }
            /* more types */
        }
    }
    any_type type;
    union {
        std::string str;
        int i;
        /* more types */
    };
};
using any_t = any::any_type;

int main() {
    std::map<std::string,any> m;
    any a;
    a.type = any_t::string_t;
    new(&(a.str)) std::string("aaa");
    //a.str = std::string{"aaa"};
    m.insert({"a",a});

    any b;
    b.type = any_t::int_t;
    b.i = 5;
    m.insert({"b",b});

    for(auto& a : m) {
        std::cout << a.second.descr() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to call placement new/placement delete on the string in the constructor/destructor as this is not done automatically for union members

Comment: @galinette Yes, you were right, thanks. I fixed it. Double-checked it with [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)